# Clone last and append item to closest class

Tags: jquery

This is the bare-bones code on my page:

```
<div class="list-container">
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
<p><button class="add-list-item">Add</button></p>

<div class="list-container">
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
<p><button class="add-list-item">Add</button></p>

<div class="list-container">
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
    <div class="single-list-item">
        <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
<p><button class="add-list-item">Add</button></p>
```

Within each `.list-container`, I'm trying to add a new `.single-list-item` by clicking the button `.add-list-item` just below it. This is the code I am using:

```
$(".add-list-item").on("click", function() {
    $(".single-list-item").last().clone().appendTo(".list-container");
});
```

This was working fine when I only had the structure once on my page, as I was working from IDs (i.e. `#list-container`), but now there are multiple and I've had to change to classes, I'm hitting problems. Namely, whenever I press the "Add" button, it adds a new `.single-list-item` to EVERY container.

I believe I'm going to need to use `.closest()` in order to specify a specific container, but I'm unsure as to how to "append to closest". Also note, the "Add" button is **not** within the container.

Comment: Pass `$(this)` from  click event and find `closest` from `$(".single-list-item").last().clone().appendTo($(this).closest(".list-container"));`

Comment: Suggestion: Always best to keep a template blank entry somewhere hidden in the DOM to clone and not clone an existing entry. Avoids all sorts of edge cases (deleting last entry etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".add-list-item").on("click", function() {
   var $container =$(this).closest('p').prev(".list-container");
   $(".single-list-item:last", $container).clone().appendTo($container);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3rs2hbo2/

When using templated rows I would recommend using a separate template element hidden somewhere in the DOM. This avoid various problems of duplicating existing content as well as the row and edge cases (like deleting the last element)

e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3rs2hbo2/1/

Where the template is hidden in a non-known script type

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
 <div class="single-list-item">
    <button>Remove</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

And the code to use it becomes:

```
$(".add-list-item").on("click", function() {
   var $container =$(this).closest('p').prev(".list-container");
   $container.append($("#template").html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
$(".add-list-item").on("click", function() {
    $(".single-list-item").last().clone().appendTo($(this).closest('p').prev(".list-container‌​"));
});
```

Comment: Actually this one is wrong too as the Add button is not inside the container.

Comment: As `.add-list-item` is not within `.list-container`, it doesn't seem like `closest()` is finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$(".add-list-item").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('p').prev('.list-container')
           .append($(".single-list-item:last").clone())
});
```